# New line printing

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to print my answer on two lines.
I tried with \n , but It was not working and I could not find exact match of my case so that I can see how exactly it has to be done.
Here is my code that should be printed. I used two print functions:

```
print ("X1 = " + "%.2f"%x1)

print ("X2 = " + "%.2f"%x2)
```

However, I would like to do it only with one print function and \n?

I tried so far with the following format of \n function:

```
print 'First line \n Second line'
```

However, as I supposed, this is not working. I am Python beginner and I know how to get to the final outcome, but I want to learn some new things and not just use the print function couple of times.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: works for me. What exactly is your output when you write `print('First line \n Second line')`?

Comment: what means " this is not working" ? Do you get error message ? Always show FULL error message (Traceback) in question. If you use Python 3 then you have to use `print()` with `()` - `print('First line \n Second line')` but in code you show without `()` - `print 'First line \n Second line'`

Comment: The format was wrong. I did not know how exactly to unite the two lines. I was trying with:
print("X1 = " + "%.2f" % x1 \n "X2 = " + "%.2f" % x2)  and such other wrong variations. Anyway, thank you both! I followed the comment below and it worked so it can be considered solved. :)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that reproduces the behavior you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print ("X1 = " + "%.2f"%x1 + "\n" + "X2 = " + "%.2f"%x2)
```

Just concat the two string you want to print with a `\n` <- new line

EDIT: 
1. more efficient way to do the same thing:

```
print("X1 = %.2f\nX2 = %.2f"%(x1,x2))
```

2. Using `format()`:

```
print("X1 = {0:.2f}\nX2 = {1:.2f}f".format(x1,x2))
```

3. Using format strings:

```
print(f"X1 = {x1:.2f}\nX2 = {x2:.2f}")
```

Comment: As easy as that. Done! Thank you!

Comment: By the way, here's a more efficient way to do the same thing: `print("X1 = %.2f\nX2 = %.2f"%(x1,x2))`

Comment: you could add this method in answer to make it more visible for other visitiors. You could even add version with `.format()` and `f" "`

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestions.